# The Fragment screen goes back to the main screen after compressing the image?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to crop and compress the image before uploading to Firebase. I have used
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper   to crop the image and
https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor to compress it.

My problem is after compressing and uploading in firebase, the fragment screen goes back to the first fragment screen.

This is my intent chooser.

```
 mProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Image"), Gallery_pick);

                 //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Image"), Gallery_pick);
        }
    });
```

This is my onActivityResult

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try{
        if(requestCode == Gallery_pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(getContext(),this);

           
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result =CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){


                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                File thum_file = new File(resultUri.getPath());

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "cropImage2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





                thumb_bitmap = null;
                try {
                    thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(getContext()).setMaxHeight(200).setMaxWidth(200).setQuality(75).compressToBitmap(thum_file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                thumb_bite = baos.toByteArray();

                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(thum_file).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_profile_blue).into(mProfile);


                final StorageReference mFilePath =  mStoragePath.child("profile_user").child(mAuth.getUid()+".jpg");

                UploadTask uploadTask = mFilePath.putBytes(thumb_bite);
                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        mFilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    imageUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                                    HashMap<String,Object> userImage = new HashMap<>();
                                    userImage.put("image",imageUrl);

                                    mUserRef.child(mAuth.getUid()).updateChildren(userImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });




            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

I am using bottom navigation. This is the way I change my fragments.

```
  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                       break;

                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                       break;

                    case R.id.nav_categories:
                        selectedFragment = new CategoriesFragment();
                        break;


                    case R.id.nav_cart:
                        selectedFragment = new CartFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_profile:
                        selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();

               return true;
            }
        };
```

please help...
I am a new in android.
I have tried every solutions from stack overflow, but it doesn't work?

Comment: Post your error log. It could be crashed the app

Comment: and also some code how do you add/switch between your `Fragment`s

Comment: @Piyush My app is not crashing. After storing the image in firebase, the fragment switches back to first fragment, that's my problem

Comment: @snachmsm I have posted the method of switching the fragments. Please check